# Ruby and integer in method name

Tags: ruby

I have to name methods based on the index number of some external documentation:

```
def 51_bic
end
```

This is wrong, as shown by the color with the syntax highlighting. And also the code fails with `` trailing `_' in number (SyntaxError) ``.

Using `bic_51` works just fine. But why is that? What's the nature of the fact that I can't use `integer + underscore + string`? My understanding is that everything after a `def` is just a method name as a string.

Comment: You _could_ create such method via `define_method('51_bic') { ... }` but it also has to be invoked via `public_send('51_bic')`. It might therefore be more convenient to add a non-numeric prefix, e.g. `index_51_bic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identifiers can have numbers in them, but can't **start** with a number. This is how it is in most programming languages (that I heard of).

> What's the nature of the problem that I can't use integer + underscore + string?

Because if you allow identifiers to start with a number, you must then mandate that they contain a letter after (to differentiate them from numbers). Now, food for thought. Imagine you *can* start identifiers with numbers. Which of these are method calls, local variables and which are number literals?

```
0xa0 + 0b10_100 + 3_456
```

Comment: Well, technically one might start method names with a digit, if the name is explicitly converted to a `Symbol`: `define_method :"51_bic" do  puts __callee__ end`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I carefully avoided using words "method name" in this answer. :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't think you need to make it a symbol. Just `define_method "51_bic" do ... end` is fine.